# Ignore persistence.xml in quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I need to import an external JAR file into my quarkus project, that contains a persistence.xml. Is there a way to ignore the embedded persistence.xml?

It should be, according to the comment in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/2d2124653d5115f85fc072ef6b5a55756039c940/extensions/hibernate-orm/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/hibernate/orm/runtime/PersistenceUnitsHolder.java#L36:

```
 * The scanner may be null to use the default scanner, or a custom scanner can be
 * used to stop Hibernate scanning. It is expected that the scanner will be
 * provided by Quarkus via its hold of Jandex info.
```

I haven't found a way to provide a custom scanner, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll find a way to do that right now and my guess is that Quarkus will fail to start if you use both `application.properties` and this `persistence.xml` in a jar. Plus having the `persistence.xml` to work in Quarkus is a bit tricky as you have to set a few advanced settings manually to be on par with Quarkus behavior.

Could you open an issue in our tracker (https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues)? Thanks!

Comment: I have added an issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6805